# If you implement deferred shading/lighting using a compute shader does having sub-passes make a difference?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

The main use of utilising sub-passes seems to be to render your G-buffer, and then in the next subpass use those G-buffer attachments as input images to read from for the shading and lighting of the scene. That would work if you did your deferred lighting/shading by rendering a full-screen quad, that way you'd be rasterising a triangle, and it could be part of a render pass subpass. The advantage of this (correct me if I'm wrong), is that the deferred shading on the second subpass could be done at the same time as the G-buffer values are being written (at the same pixel).

Question 1: Is the above right?

Question 2: Given that today the trend is to use compute shaders when traditionally you would render a quad and use the graphics pipeline, does using a compute shader to do shading/lighting and reading from the G-buffer throw away a potential optimisation on tile-based GPUs that could be have been had by doing your lighting/shading rendering a full-screen quad?

Comment: "*Given that today the trend is to use compute shaders when traditionally you would render a quad and use the graphics pipeline*" [citation needed] Also, I fail to see any material difference from your last question, the [answer to which](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72662820/734069) explains what you give up by doing it this way.

Comment: @NicolBolas That wasn't MY question, but its answer addresses my question.

Comment: I'm very curious to know how it is that two separate people got the idea that "today the trend is to use compute shaders" for deferred rendering. Is there some resource out there saying this and citing examples? Does Unity or UE do this?

Comment: @NicolBolas It sounds like that other OP claimed that deferred shading/lighting was trending toward being done with compute shader. I meant generally using compute shaders when fragment shader/graphics pipeline isn't needed, I didn't mean for deferred shading/lighting (I don't know how this is commonly done). However why do you need the graphics pipeline and fragment shader to do deferred shading/lighting? Am I right in thinking the only reason it's done with the fragment shader is to allow the extra optimisation for tile-based renderers?